# Receiving UDP Packets Asynchronously From Multiple File Descriptors

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, asynchronous

I have a questions about using fcntl and sigaction to receive a UDP packet asynchronously. In my program I have two sources of UDP traffic that I would like to monitor.  I have set up two sockets for the traffic and used [this](http://www.lindusembedded.com/blog/2008/11/06/simple-udp-client-server-with-asynchronous-io/) tutorial to set the file descriptor to trigger a sigaction whenever I receive a UDP packet.

This works fine with only one source, but when I add the other source it will trigger only one of the handlers whenever either file descriptor receives a packet.

Here is a short program demonstrating the behavior:

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int done;
int a_fd;
int b_fd;

int recv_dgram(int fd, char* dgram, int size)
{
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int fromlen = sizeof(addr);
    return recvfrom(fd, dgram, size, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, (socklen_t*)&fromlen);
}

void a_handler(int signum)
{
    char dgram[256];
    int size = recv_dgram(a_fd, dgram, 256);
    printf("a recieve size: %d\n", size);
}

void b_handler(int signum)
{
    char dgram[256];
    int size = recv_dgram(b_fd, dgram, 256);
    printf("b recieve size: %d\n", size);
}

void sig_handle(int signum)
{
    done = 1;
}

int init_fd(int port, const char* group, const char* interface)
{
    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(fd < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    int reuse = 1;
    if(setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0) {
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }

    if(fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) < 0) {
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset((char*)&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if(bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr))) {
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }

    struct ip_mreq mcast_group;
    mcast_group.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(group);
    mcast_group.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr(interface);
    if(setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char*)&mcast_group, sizeof(mcast_group))) {
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }

    return fd;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    done = 0;
    signal(SIGINT, sig_handle);
    signal(SIGTERM, sig_handle);

    // make sockets and sigactions
    a_fd = init_fd([a port], [a multicast group], [a interface]);
    if(a_fd < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    pid_t pid = getpid();

    int a_flags = fcntl(a_fd, F_GETFL);
    fcntl(a_fd, F_SETFL, a_flags | O_ASYNC);

    struct sigaction a_sa;
    a_sa.sa_flags = 0;
    a_sa.sa_handler = a_handler;
    sigemptyset(&a_sa.sa_mask);

    sigaction(SIGIO, &a_sa, NULL);
    fcntl(a_fd, F_SETOWN, pid);
    fcntl(a_fd, F_SETSIG, SIGIO);

    b_fd = init_fd([b port], [b multicast group], [b interface]);
    if(b_fd < 0) {
        close(a_fd);
        return -1;
    }

    int b_flags = fcntl(b_fd, F_GETFL);
    fcntl(b_fd, F_SETFL, b_flags | O_ASYNC);

    struct sigaction b_sa;
    b_sa.sa_flags = 0;
    b_sa.sa_handler = b_handler;
    sigemptyset(&b_sa.sa_mask);

    sigaction(SIGIO, &b_sa, NULL);
    fcntl(b_fd, F_SETOWN, pid);
    fcntl(b_fd, F_SETSIG, SIGIO);

    printf("start\n");
    while(!done) { pause(); }
    printf("done\n");

    close(a_fd);
    close(b_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

I can compile this with (you can compile using gcc too):

g++ -c test.cpp

g++ -o test test.o

I'm using g++ 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

When I run this program with two sources of UDP data, b_handler gets triggered when either file descriptors has a packet available.  So it will print "b received size: -1" whenever a_handler should receive a packet. a_handler never gets called.

I suspect that this is because getpid() will return the same value for both of them so one of the sigaction handler will be overwritten.

Is there any way I can have these two handlers trigger independent of each other?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why can you not use select/poll and friends? This is the normal way of multiplexing multiple inputs. You can do very little safely in a signal handler.

Comment: This should be the way I accomplish this and I will do that in the future. I mostly did it this way to try something new and was curious if there was a way around this  pitfall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two different signals, say SIGIO and SIGUSR1.

```
fcntl(descriptor, SETSIG, signal_desired);
```